# How to compare elements in an array with indexPath.item?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

item added to the array when I am using didSelectItemAt indexPath
and the array contains more than one element, but only one cell has the picture "Rectangle Filled"

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    indexSelected = indexPath.item

    if trashButtonIsActive == true   {
        selectedItems.append(indexPath.item)
        // I am adding indexPath.item to the array.Which need to compare with indexPath.item in cellForItemAt method.//
    } else if trashButtonIsActive == false  {
        if selectedItems.count != 0 {
            selectedItems.removeAll()
        }

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "cardView", sender: indexPath)
    }

    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if trashButtonIsActive == true && selectedItems.count == 0 {
        let  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.labelText = array![indexPath.item].frontal
        cell.buttonToTrash.setImage(UIImage(named: "Rectangle Empty"), for: .normal)
        return cell
    }else if trashButtonIsActive == true && selectedItems.count != 0 {
        for index in selectedItems {
            //I don't know why , but it compares only first element in the array //
            if indexPath.item != index {
                let  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
                cell.labelText = array![indexPath.item].frontal
                cell.buttonToTrash.setImage(UIImage(named: "Rectangle Empty"), for: .normal)
                return cell
            }else{
                let  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
                cell.labelText = array![indexPath.item].frontal
                cell.buttonToTrash.setImage(UIImage(named: "Rectangle Filled"), for: .normal)
                return cell
            }
        }
    }else if trashButtonIsActive == false  {
        let  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.labelText = array![indexPath.item].frontal
        cell.buttonToTrash.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
        return cell
    }

    let cellTwo = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell hello", for: indexPath)
    return cellTwo
}
```

I want indexPath.row's which are equal to the elements in the array to have the picture "Rectangle Filled". Would anyone be able to assist?

Comment: It's a collection view, so you should use `indexPath.item`, not `row`. You should track selection state in your model, but if you do want to track selection state in another object, use a `Set<IndexPath>` rather than an array

Comment: I am new to programming, I don't know how to track selection state in model.Could you help me with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your model like this

```
struct ModelName{
var name: String
var rectangle: Bool
}
```

then you array which is selected items will be like this

```
var selectedItems = [ModelName]()
```

then in viewdidload or anywhere you are trying to initialise data you can do this

```
selectedItems.apped(ModelName(name: "name", rectangle: false)
selectedItems.apped(ModelName(name: "new", rectangle: true)
selectedItems.apped(ModelName(name: "newname", rectangle: false)
selectedItems.apped(ModelName(name: "namename", rectangle: false)
```

etc

then for cellforrow at do this

```
let item = selectedItems[indexPath.item]
cell.textlabel.text = item.name
if item.rectangle == true{
cell.rectButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "rectangle", for: .normal)
}else{
cell.rectButton.setImage(nil, for: .normal)}
return cell
```

I have tried with just name and rectangle you can do whatever you want if you don't want to initialse with any value make that variable nil